# SpringBoot execute custom configuration before DataSourceAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, datasource

Is there a way to insert a custom configuration before `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` is run? I want to create and start a docker container before spring creates the `DataSource` instance, but I still want to keep the spring autoconfiguration benefits and customization (as I don't need to modify any `DataSource` related logic itself), that is, I don't want to manually create a `DataSource` bean overriding autoconfiguration.

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you figured it out since then?

Answer (score 1):

Even if this question is outdated, searching for the same thing I found the annotation `@AutoConfigureOrder` that have a default value of 0 and it seems to work well.

Maybe can be useful for someone.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this for Spring Boot 1.3 or greater:

```
@AutoConfigureBefore({DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class DockerAutoConfiguration {
  ..
}
```

Comment: I've added this annotation but it still tries to create a DataSource before it runs the configuration file.